# Is there any Listener for Perspective Loading?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

like IExecutionListener for ResetPerspective, with this listener I can measure the time to Reset a Perspective by using preExecute() and postExecuteSuccess() Methods.So is there any listener like this to know before execution and after execution of a particular Perspective Loading ?

Comment: Not that I know of. There is an `IPerspectiveListener` but it doesn't cover loading.

Comment: is there any other approach to measure perspective loading time ?